# Pandas conditional formatting not working with to_html()

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to send an e-mail containing a ***styled*** Pandas dataframe in the e-mail body.

I'm able to build the e-mail successfully, but it does ***not*** contain the styling (although it ***does*** contain the styling when viewed in a Jupyter notebook).

Here is my code:

First, build the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
        'id' : [1, 2, 3],
        'name' : ['John Smith', 'Sally Jones', 'William Lee']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    id  name
0   1   John Smith
1   2   Sally Jones
2   3   William Lee
```

Then, style the dataframe:

```
highlighted_rows = np.where(df['name'] == 'Sally Jones',
                                'background-color: lightgreen',
                                '')

df.style.apply(lambda _: highlighted_rows)
```

Which gives the following in a Jupyter notebook:

[image]

Then, build the HTML for the e-mail body:

```
html = f"""\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hi All,<br>
      <br>
      Here is the report.<br>
      <br>
      Report details:<br>
      --------
      {df.to_html()}<br>
      <br>
    </p>  
  </body>
</html>
"""
```

When I print the `html` object, I see the following:

```
html

'<html>\n  <head></head>\n  <body>\n    <p>\n      Hi All,<br>\n      <br>\n      Here is the report.<br>\n      <br>\n      Report details:<br>\n      --------\n      <table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>id</th>\n      <th>name</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>1</td>\n      <td>John Smith</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>1</th>\n      <td>2</td>\n      <td>Sally Jones</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2</th>\n      <td>3</td>\n      <td>William Lee</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table><br>\n      <br>\n    </p>  \n  </body>\n</html>\n'
```

How can I get the HTML in the e-mail body to take the row styling?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you want to send the email & check their rendering? Via python? Modern email program allow you to modify html.

Comment: The entire pipeline is done via Python (e.g. query SQL database, build `df`, build e-mail, send e-mail).  The e-mail client is not involved in any way.  I send the e-mail using `MIMEMultipart`.

Answer (score 0):

[Styler.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) returns a `Styler` object, you need use this object to export to styled html

```py
s = df.style.apply(lambda _: highlighted_rows)

s.to_html()
```

Comment: I created an `s` object and then passed `s.to_html()` into the f-string as `{s.to_html()}<br>`.  There is no effect.  Is there any other "plumbing" that I need to do to get this working?  Thanks.

Comment: @zeroes_ones You can check the output of `s.to_html()`, it returns the styled table with the [internal CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_css.asp) tag `<style>`. You may need to split the output of `s.to_html()` and place `<style>` into `<head>` section.